# Beacon background service sometimes is killed from Android

Tags: android, service, beacon

I'm using the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/download.html) 2.0 and I have a strange problem with the beacon background service. I start manually my app at least once, I switch off my device and restart. If I go to the list of running app/services, I see the name of my app (1 process, 1 service) but after a few seconds it disappears from the list as killed from Android. Sometimes after 2 or 3 minutes it appears again but after a few seconds il disappears. 
This behaviour is not the "rule", sometimes the service runs without problems and remains active.

This is my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/my_drawable"
    android:label="MyApp"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" 
    android:name="BeaconReferenceApplication">
    <activity
        android:name="org.altbeacon.beaconreference.MonitoringActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
        android:label="MyApp" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="org.altbeacon.beaconreference.RangingActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
        android:label="MyApp" >
        <intent-filter>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

For tests I'm using Samsung Galaxy tab3 (Android 4.4.2) and Samsung Galaxy tab4 (Android 4.4.2)

I've tried to check the logcat message and these lines maybe could explain something.

> E/BeaconManager( 4802): Cannot contact service to set scan periods
>
> D/BeaconManager( 4802): This consumer is not bound.  binding:
>   org.altbeacon.beaconreference.BeaconReferenceApplication@42320918
>
> D/BeaconManager( 4802): consumer count is now:1
>
> V/ApplicationPolicy( 2365): isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname
>   org.altbeacon.beaconreference
>
> D/CustomFrequencyManagerService( 2365): acquireDVFSLockLocked : type :
>   DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1400000  uid : 1000  pid : 2365  pkgName :
>   ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@5
>
> W/ActivityManager( 2365): mDVFSHelper.acquire()
>
> D/PhoneStatusBar( 2551): setTransGradationMode=false,
>   mTransparentMode=false, mSemiTransparentMode=false,
>   mMultiWindowMode=false
>
> W/ResourceType( 2365): No known package when getting value for
>   resource number 0x7f020000
>
> D/StatusBarManagerService( 2365): tr p:2365,o:f
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365): Token{432ad010 ActivityRecord{432ace98 u0
>   org.altbeacon.beaconreference/.MonitoringActivity t3}} failed creating
>   starting window
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365):
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020000
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365):   at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2354)
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365):   at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1919)
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365):   at
>   com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.setIcon(ActionBarView.java:1037)
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365):   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3478)
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365):   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1886)
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365):   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.addStartingWindow(PhoneWindowManager.java:2639)
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365):   at
>   com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:9140)
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365):   at adroid.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
>
> D/PointerIcon( 2365): setMouseIconStyle1 pointerType: 1001iconType:101
>   flag:0
>
> D/PointerIcon( 2365): setMouseCustomIcon IconType is same.101
>
> I/BeaconService( 4802): beaconService version 2.0-samsung1 is starting
>   up
>
> I/BeaconService( 4802): SDK is 18 or higher.  Using native Android
>   APIs for BLE scanning
>
> ---
>
> D/PhoneStatusBar( 2551): setTransGradationMode=false,
>   mTransparentMode=false, mSemiTransparentMode=false,
>   mMultiWindowMode=false
>
> W/ResourceType( 2365): No known package when getting value for
>   resource number 0x7f020000
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365): Token{4335a9f8 ActivityRecord{4335a880 u0
>   org.altbeacon.beaconreference/.RangingActivity t3}} failed creating
>   starting window
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365):
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020000
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365):   at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2354)
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365):   at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1919)
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365):   at
>   com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.setIcon(ActionBarView.java:1037)
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365):   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3478)
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365):   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1886)
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365):   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.addStartingWindow(PhoneWindowManager.java:2639)
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365):   at
>   com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:9140)
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> W/WindowManager( 2365):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>
> ### W/WindowManager( 2365):   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
>
> D/BtGatt.GattService( 3581): onScanResult() -
>   address=F4:B8:5E:E4:BA:4A, rssi=-53
>
> D/BtGatt.GattService( 3581): Binder is dead - unregistering client
>   (5)!
>
> E/BtGatt.GattService( 3581): Exception: android.os.DeadObjectException
>
> W/InputDispatcher( 2365): channel ~ Consumer closed input channel or
>   an error occurred.  events=0x9
>
> I/WindowState( 2365): WIN DEATH: Window{43379c08 u0
>   org.altbeacon.beaconreference/org.altbeacon.beaconreference.RangingActivity}
>
> E/InputDispatcher( 2365): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken
>   and will be disposed!
>
> W/InputDispatcher( 2365): Attempted to unregister already unregistered
>   input channel
>
> ### I/WindowState( 2365): WIN DEATH: Window{43366f58 u0 org.altbeacon.beaconreference/org.altbeacon.beaconreference.MonitoringActivity}

My app detects correctly all the beacons in range, but I need a working background service in order to work on long periods. 
Could you please suggest me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I can assume that if I see the application with "1 process and 1 service" is in the list of running programs, the service is active and running and if I can't see it the process is not running?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding I am thinking that Whichever application i develop using concept of Beacons.

I will run my service till my activity is running in background. When my application will be cleared by user i will stop scanning all beacons.
My opinion is to run service only when activity bounded to it is running or else just stop service. That will also affect to device battery.

For binding a service to activity you can look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html).

Hope It will help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately your answer doesn't help me so much... however I will read the info on the dev manual about binding.

Comment: I can assume that if I see the application with "1 process and 1 service" is in the list of running programs, the service is active and running and if I can't see it the process is not running?

Comment: @Ant4res : you checked this in 'Running application' section right? If yes then It is true that if you can't see it the process is not running..!!